# Gridview c# no muestra datos

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo el siguiente problema: Consumo un webservice rest para llenar una lista de empleados. Despues usó esa lista para llenar un Gridview pero al momento de ejecutar el DataBind no me pinta nada en el formulario:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
namespace WebServiceNetClienteRest{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page {
        List<Empleado> empleados = null;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
            grdEmpleados.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        }
        protected void btnListar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            Task tsk = consumir();
        }
        protected async Task consumir(){
            try{
                HttpClient clientWS = new HttpClient();
                clientWS.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/JavaWebServiceServerCRUDRestful/restful/empleados/json/listarempleados/");
                clientWS.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                clientWS.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpResponseMessage response = await clientWS.GetAsync("");
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
                    System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
                    string cadena = encoding.GetString(response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result);
                    empleados = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Empleado>>(cadena);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\n\n\n");
                    foreach (var empleado in empleados){
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Id={0}\nNombre={1}\nEmpleado={2}", empleado.Id, empleado.Nombre, empleado.Puesto);   
                    }
                }
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\n\n\n");
                grdEmpleados.DataSource = empleados;
                grdEmpleados.Visible = true;
                grdEmpleados.DataBind();
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\n\n\n***************:"+e.Message+ "\n\n\n*****************");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Y este es el aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebServiceNetClienteRest.WebForm1"  %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text="ID:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtId" runat="server" Width="142px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblNombre" runat="server" Text="Nombre:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNombre" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblPuesto" runat="server" Text="Puesto:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPuesto" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnListar" runat="server" OnClick="btnListar_Click" Text="Listar" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="grdEmpleados" runat="server" >
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Al debuggear los datos si estan en la lista empleados y se asignan correctamente al grdEmpleados, pero no se porque no aparecen en el formulario, incluso pinta esto en la consola de visual studio:

```
Id=1
Nombre=Andres
Empleado=Desarrollador
Id=2
Nombre=Abraham
Empleado=Programador
```

¿Alguien puede apoyarme? Es que soy muy novato en este lenguaje.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El tema es que estas trabajando con metodo asigcronos, no uses el HttpClient usa el WebClient

```
protected void consumir()
{
    try
    {
        var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/JavaWebServiceServerCRUDRestful/restful/empleados/json/listarempleados/");
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";

        string cadena = "";
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            cadena = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
         }

        var empleados = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Empleado>>(cadena);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\n\n\n");
        foreach (var empleado in empleados){
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Id={0}\nNombre={1}\nEmpleado={2}", empleado.Id, empleado.Nombre, empleado.Puesto);   
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\n\n\n");

        grdEmpleados.DataSource = empleados;
        grdEmpleados.Visible = true;
        grdEmpleados.DataBind();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\n\n\n***************:"+e.Message+ "\n\n\n*****************");
    }
}
```

de esta forma no tendras problemas con la asincronia que carga los datos del gridview

Comment: gracias, ya me funciono